# I cannot see doctrine:generate:migration command in symfony2

Tags: symfony, netbeans

I am new in PHP programing and a am trying to using Symfony2 framework NetBeans IDE 8.1.0. I created PHP project in  NetBeans IDE 8.1.0 choosen Symfony 2 PHP Web Framework, referenced it to the Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.5.6.zip and C:\xampp\php\php.exe files. On right click on created project and 
choose simfony2->Run Command I don't see  doctrine:generate:migration. What else do I should install to see be able to use that commans?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @user3475484 you should check [DoctrineMigrationBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html). Ya you are right we cann't found this console command in standard Symfony2 package because it is not part of Symfony2 standard vendors. 
   So you have to install doctrine migration bundle as suggest in [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) link.